# Extract last delivery for each name on each date

Tags: java, stream

I've been using Java 8 Stream features quite a lot these days and am very happy with it. I've written a code that uses groupingBy and max but was wondering if it can still be optimized or even just be tweaked for better readability.

Some sample data:

```
Name, OrderDate, DeliveryTime
abc, 2010-01-15, 2010-01-15T11:00:00
abc, 2010-01-15, 2010-01-31T07:00:00 //should be marked as latest
zzz, 2010-01-15, 2010-01-13T11:00:00
zzz, 2010-01-15, 2010-01-23T07:00:00 //should be marked as latest
```

Here's the code I've written:

```
public class DeliveryTest {
   class Delivery {
      String name;
      LocalDate orderDate;
      LocalDateTime deliveryTime;
      boolean isLatest = false;
      //getters and setters here
   }

   @Test
   public void testLatestDelivery() {
      List<Delivery> deliveries = new ArrayList<>();
      //populate the test data here

      //group the deliveries by name and orderDate 
      Map<String, Map<LocalDate, List<Delivery>>> groupByNameAndOrderDate = deliveries.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Delivery::getName, groupingBy(Delivery::getOrderDate)));

      //find and mark as "Latest" for each of the the max deliveryTime per name and orderDate grouping, 
      groupByNameAndOrderDate.forEach((name, byNameMap) -> {
          byNameMap.forEach((orderDate, byOrderDateList) -> {
              byOrderDateList.stream()
                  .max((n1, n2) -> n1.getDeliveryTime().compareTo(n2.getDeliveryTime())).get()
                  .setIsLatest(true);
          });
      });
      //do assertions here
   }
}
```

Can this Java 8 code still be improved (for example the part where I have nested forEach)?

Or written shorter but still readable (for example, can the group and max be combined)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could short-hand your `max()` function with the use of `Comparator.comparing()`

```
byOrderDateList.stream()
  .max(Comparator.comparing(Delivery::deliveryTime)).get()
  .setIsLatest(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Simplification

Other than [@JudeNiroshan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158005/24141)'s suggestion of using a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), you also do not need the `{ ... }` style for one-liner lambdas. Your approach can be *slightly* simplified to:

```
@Test
public void testLatestDelivery() {
    List<Delivery> deliveries = createTestDeliveries();
    deliveries.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Delivery::getName, groupingBy(Delivery::getOrderDate)))
        .forEach((name, byNameMap) -> byNameMap.forEach((orderDate, byOrderDateList) ->
                byOrderDateList.stream()
                        .max(Comparator.comparing(Delivery::getDeliveryTime)).get()
                        .setIsLatest(true)));
    // ...
}
```

#### Key-ing your domain object

Ordinarily, a common suggestion when you want to key your domain object is to create an intermediary class that encapsulates the uniqueness of its objects. However, if such a key is only a temporary requirement and you do not foresee reusing it elsewhere, you might be able to get away with a simple hash value derivation using [`Objects.hash(Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-):

```
Function<Delivery, Integer> withKey = delivery ->
        Objects.hash(delivery.getName(), delivery.getOrderDate());
```

With this derivation, you can continue using your `groupingBy(Function, Collector)`, but this time round you can also immediately substitute in the use of [`Collectors.maxBy(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-) so that your final (?) `Map` is typed as `Map<Integer, Optional<Delivery>>`.

Putting it altogether:

```
@Test
public void testLatestDelivery() {
    Function<Delivery, Integer> withKey = delivery ->
            Objects.hash(delivery.getName(), delivery.getOrderDate());
    List<Delivery> deliveries = createTestDeliveries();
    deliveries.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(withKey, maxBy(comparing(Delivery::getDeliveryTime))))
        .forEach((hashKey, delivery) -> delivery.get().setIsLatest(true));
    // ...
}
```

*Footnote:*

*I will not recommend using the `Map` class liberally for a two-key encapsulation, because a `Map` suggests a key-value relationship between the two... keys. Thus, if the hash value derivation is not to your liking, please do spend that bit more effort with a `DeliveryKey` class to better represent how a `Delivery` can be grouped with its name and order date, instead of just a `Map`. The `DeliveryKey` class will need to carefully implement `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()`, [of course](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java?rq=1).*